# View pager does not inflate the good page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to use a view pager to make a gallery. Nevertheless it's always the view at the position 1 which is updated whereas i'm trying to update the current page (0 by default).

First of all i have created a view which gonna be inflated by the pager. This view is composed of 4 ImageView and 4 textview.

Then i created a adapter for the pager :

```
public class LivePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private CameraList cameras = null;

    public LivePagerAdapter(CameraList cams)
    {
        this.cameras = cams;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.cameras.size() /4; // 4 imageview in a page
    }

    public void setCameras(CameraList cams)
    {
        this.cameras = cams;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager,null);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Finally in my activity i'm instanciate the pager like this :

```
adapter = new LivePagerAdapter(this.listeCamera);
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.camspager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
pager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

After that i'm initialising a array with my 4 imageview :

```
tabImageView.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cam1)); //Imageview located in the view loaded by the pager
tabImageView.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cam2));
tabImageView.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cam3));
tabImageView.add((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cam4));
```

And when needed i add a image in the imageview.

It seems to works except that i'm asking the pager to start at position 0 and this is the view from position 1 which is updated with my images.

When i use `findViewById(somethingInflatedByThePager)` i need it to be the current page , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you replace `((ViewPager) container).addView(view,0);` by `((ViewPager) container).addView(view);`

Comment: Good to ear that it helps you. Don't forget that if you use eclipse, when you put your cursor on a method, you can have a quick description like : void android.view.ViewGroup.addView(View child, int index)

public void addView (View child, int index)
Since: API Level 1
Adds a child view. If no layout parameters are already set on the child, the default parameters for this ViewGroup are set on the child.

Parameters
**child the child view to add**
**index the position at which to add the child**